# How to get total time % for different codes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table called Timetable and the data looks like:

```
Hours   Code    FiMonth  Mgr
16      OT      2011M1   Sam
0.25    DT      2011M1   Peter
1.75    HNE     2011M1   george
6.5     DT      2010M1   Peter
3.25    OT      2010M1   Sam
0.5     DT      2010M2   Sam
30      HNE     2011M1   John
```

Now I have to calculate the time% and the formula to get that value is:

> Time% = Sum(DT+OT) Hours/(DT+OT+HNE)Hours

I wrote the query as:

```
SELECT  ( ( SELECT  SUM(CONVERT(FLOAT, [Hours])) AS [Hours]
            FROM    Timetable d
            WHERE   d.code IN ( 'OT','DT') 
          )
          / ( SELECT    SUM(CONVERT(FLOAT, [Hours])) AS [Hours]
              FROM      Timetable t
              WHERE     t.code IN ( 'OT', 'DT','HNE')
           ) ) AS Time%
           FROM    Timetable
           GROUP BY Mgr
```

I have to use this value in my Stored Procedure and I have many Columns like this. So, I don't want to write this much code for one column.

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH Timetable([Hours],code,FiMonth,Mgr) as
(
SELECT 16,'OT','2011M1','Sam' UNION ALL
SELECT 0.25,'DT','2011M1','Peter' UNION ALL
SELECT 1.75,'HNE','2011M1','george' UNION ALL
SELECT 6.5,'DT','2010M1','Peter' UNION ALL
SELECT 3.25,'OT','2010M1','Sam' UNION ALL
SELECT 0.5,'DT','2010M2','Sam' UNION ALL
SELECT 30,'HNE','2011M1','John'
)
SELECT Mgr,
       SUM(CASE
             WHEN code IN ( 'OT', 'DT' ) THEN CAST([Hours] AS FLOAT)
             ELSE 0
           END)/ NULLIF(SUM(CAST([Hours] AS FLOAT)),0) AS [Time%]
FROM   Timetable t
WHERE  code IN ( 'OT', 'DT', 'HNE' )
GROUP  BY Mgr
```

Comment: @Martin This is the Error I am getting   Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator.

Comment: @Sam - Ah I assumed the cast to float was just to avoid integer division. Should work now. Why are the hours `varchar`?

Comment: @Martin I dont know the data they gave me is like that. I didn't design the table

Comment: @Martin It gives me Divide by Zero Error

Comment: @Sam - make the divisor `NULLIF(0,SUM(CAST([Hours] AS FLOAT)))` then.

Comment: @Martin Still I get this error   Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Divide by zero error encountered.

Comment: @Martin I am using group by for that query

Comment: Doesn't seem possible that its coming from that divide operation then. `NULLIF(0,exp)` will return `NULL` if `expr=0` (meaning that the division as a whole returns `NULL`)

Comment: @Martin I am using this in my stored procedure where they are grouping this column by manager name

Comment: It doesn't matter where you are using it. If the bottom half of the division can never be zero then you should never get a divide by zero error.

Comment: @martin what else that error could mean other than that I know that I do have some zero for that column

Comment: @Sam - Does the `/` operator exist anywhere else in that query?

Comment: @Martin Nope. I just added group by caluse to the query nothing else I have added

Comment: Can you update your question with the actual code you are running then?

Comment: @Martin I have the actual code I am executing at the bottom of my question

Comment: @Sam - I'm an idiot! It should have been `NULLIF(SUM(CAST([Hours] AS FLOAT)),0)`